# Docker | PM2 | Bash - PM2 error: Error: Interpreter bash is NOT AVAILABLE in PATH

Tags: bash, docker, shell, devops, pm2

I'm trying to Dockerize a pm2 server that runs a shell script but I keep receiving this error
`PM2 error: Error: Interpreter bash is NOT AVAILABLE in PATH`. The shell script works directly in the terminal and is able to log "Testing" and when I run the shell script inside Docker without pm2 is also logged "Testing". I tried using the command `which bash` to get the correct path and it returns `/usr/bin/bash`. The path was added to the config file but the error persists.

start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Testing"
```

ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    script: './start.sh',
    intepreter: '#!/bin/sh',
  }]
};
```

DockerFile

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest-alpine

COPY . .

RUN npm install pm2 -g

ENV PM2_PUBLIC_KEY <public key>
ENV PM2_SECRET_KEY <secret key>

COPY ecosystem.config.js .

CMD ["chmod", "+x", "./start.sh"]

CMD ["pm2-runtime","start","ecosystem.config.js"]
```

Error Im receiving
`PM2 error: Error: Interpreter bash is NOT AVAILABLE in PATH`

Answer (score 0):

There is no `bash` command in this docker image.
instead of that, you can use `ash` or `sh` commands.

to check the image contains the specific command like bash, try to use this:

```
docker run --rm -it --name <container_name> <image_name> bash
```

and change bash with `ash` or `sh` if bash does not work. if this command works, you will enter the container command line.

Comment: Are you referring to this docker image ```FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest-alpine```?

Comment: yes. I checked that images for you right now. there is no bash command in that image.

Comment: If I were to look up a new Docker image how would I know it contains bash commands?

Comment: try this command:
`docker run --rm -it --name <container_name> <image_name> <bash or ash or sh>`
and change bash with ash or sh if bash does not work. if this command works, you will enter the container comand line.

Comment: I ran the command with sh and ash and the error still persists.